page.evaluateOnNewDocument doesn't work after compilation PKG
this code works as it should if you run it through node index.js, but after compilation pkg stops working.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const findChrome = require('chrome-finder');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const UserAgent = require('user-agents');
const stealth = StealthPlugin();
puppeteer.use(stealth);

initialization();

async function initialization() {
  const chromePath = findChrome();
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: chromePath,
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-infobars',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',

      '--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-gpu',

      '--lang=en',

      '--window-position=0,0',
      '--test-type',
      '--disable-features=site-per-process', // ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold,
      '--ignore-certificate-errors',
      // '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs',
    ],
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation', '--mute-audio'],
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });

  browser.on('targetcreated', async target => {
    try {
      if (target.type() === 'page') {
        const newPage = await target.page();
        // const url = newPage.url();
        newPage &&
          newPage.on('framenavigated', async frame => {
            try {
              const newURL = frame?.url();
              if (newURL && newURL.includes('https://www.example.com')) {
                const allTimezones = moment.tz.names();
                const randomTimezoneIndex = Math.floor(
                  Math.random() * allTimezones.length
                );
                const randomTimezone = allTimezones[randomTimezoneIndex];
                const ua = new UserAgent({});
                const { userAgent, viewportWidth, viewportHeight, platform } =
                  ua.data;

                await newPage.setUserAgent(userAgent);
                await newPage.setViewport({
                  width: viewportWidth,
                  height: viewportHeight,
                });
                await newPage.emulateTimezone(randomTimezone);
                await newPage.setBypassCSP(true);
                await newPage.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
                  console.log('window', window);
                  Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
                    value: {
                      getItem: () => null, // Имитация пустого localStorage
                      setItem: () => null,
                      removeItem: () => null,
                      clear: () => null,
                    },
                    writable: false, // Запрет на изменение localStorage
                    configurable: false, // Запрет на удаление localStorage
                    enumerable: true,
                  });
                });

                await newPage.goto('https://www.google.com');
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('framenavigated err', error.message);
            }
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('targetcreated err', error.message);
    }
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
}


manifest script
  "scripts": {
    "pkg": "pkg ./src/index.js -c ./pkgConfig.json",
  },


pkgConfig.json
 {
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "node_modules/chrome-finder/**/*",
      "node_modules/moment-timezone/**/*",
      "node_modules/puppeteer/**/*",
      "node_modules/puppeteer-core/**/*",
      "node_modules/puppeteer-extra/**/*",
      "node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/**/*",
      "node_modules/user-agents/**/*"
    ],
    "outputPath": "dist/build"
  }
}



Actually, when running the code through node index.js, localstrge is overwritten and access to local storage for Google is blocked, but after copying there is no
?????????????????

https://i.sstatic.net/OHFtq.png

Thanks for the update, but I'm still not seeing your motivation for all this code. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Now the error is gone completely so I'm not sure what the issue is.

there is no error but the code is not executed, I expect that Google will not be able to save the data to local storage, and if I run the code in the terminal directly through node. Everything works as it should. but as soon as js is packaged with pkg it stops working.

OK, but what are you trying to accomplish? Disable local storage? There's probably a better way to do it than this.

yes I want to disable local storage for some sites.
For example ?)

OK, thanks. Can you [edit] that all into the question so it's totally clear on its own? Then I'll delete my comments.
